# jquery mobile scrollview on click

Tags: jquery, mobile, scrollview, scrollto

I am testing the scrollview horizontal direction and from this experiment: http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html.

My version is available here: http://www.terencetengker.nl/scrollview/index.html . This version is functional and scrolls left/right on touch swipe or mouse swipe commands (Chrome 12). I cannot figure out how to scroll left/right via buttons or mouse clicks?

Clicking on BIG wil change the css so the boxes resize to fit the window. I have multiple buttons (with different methods) in the boxes to scroll the boxes left and right. None of them work.

Someone any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Found out that it was in the scrollTo function, just in case anyone needs this! :)